# MongoDB container with Spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, testcontainers

Got stuck with authentication problems using spring boot 3 + testcontainers (MongoDb container, image: mongo:6.0.13-jammy).
The exception thrown: 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost: 49123.

My config for the container:
I read about no-user + password for mongo, I also tried admin + admin, I tried non-root user,
with the same problem.

Here is my config:
'mongodb:
main:
username: "admin" <--also tried using empty username
authenticationDatabase: "admin"
database:  "test"
password:  "admin" <--also tried using empty password`

Here is my debug screenshot for MongoCredential:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/f3my5xvyssl7bxgao3jpq/MONGO.png?rlkey=koai9nkgsvsa8ijww7epdy5xt&dl=0
During debugging I was able to connect to mongo with MongoDB Compass.
However, in my container logs I observed exception like: "could not find user "admin" for db "test" [or "admin" when I set "admin" db].

I also tried using PLAIN connectionString, but it seems to me that mongo does not build user during container startup.
I also tried init-script for startup container, though I did not observe any user created on startup.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem recently, but for me the problem was definitely related to the MongoDB container not providing any user. However, manually creating a user through `mongosh` did work. Can you show us your MongoDB container configuration (like a `docker-compose.yml` or something?). Also, in an unrelated note... is that Comic Sans in your IDE? 

Comment: That's it, I love funny staff during dev days.